# Surjectivity of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=(x+1)/(x-2)$

Tags: functions

I know the following function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-2}$ is not 'onto' , but I don't know how to prove it.

I got this far

$f(x)=y$ take any $y\in\mathbb{R}$

$\frac{x+1}{x-2}=y$

$x=\frac{1-2y}{1-y}$

Comment: Can you get the value $1$?  Note that your inverse function is singular at $y=1$.

Comment: Worth noting:  your inverse function is not correct.  At $y=0$ you get $x=1$ but $f(1)\neq 0$.  Check your arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is false; it should be $f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$. On the other hand, if $x \in D(f)$ and $y \in Im(f)$, we have the equivalence
$$
f(x) = y \Longleftrightarrow x = \frac{2 y + 1}{y - 1}\mbox{.}
$$
This function is biyective (injective and surjective).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE :: DOMAIN OF FUNCTION CANNOT BE R AS $x \neq 2$
$$. $$ If $ y=\frac{ax+b}{px+q} \,,\, x \neq \frac{-q}{p}$ we can write it as 
$$y=\frac{a}{p} (\frac{x+g}{x+f})$$
Where $g=\frac{b}{a}\,,\,\,f=\frac{q}{p}$
$$y=\frac{a}{p} (\frac{x+f+g-f}{x+f})$$
$$y=\frac{a}{p} (1+\frac{g-f}{x+f})$$
$$(y-\frac{a}{p})=\frac{a}{p}( \frac{g-f}{x+f})$$
Since RHS $\neq 0$ Hence $y \neq \frac{a}{p}$
$$\therefore y \neq 1$$